# Explode array and set as associative with default values?

Tags: php, arrays

0I have this string:

```
01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09
```

and I need to convert it in an associative array with the numbers as keys and the values set to 0

```
Array(
   "01" => 0,
   "02" => 0,
   etc
)
```

I've found the function [array_walk](https://www.php.net/array_walk) but if I try to use it:
http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/5z2-bar

```
$string = "01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09";
$days = explode(",", $string);

$assDays = Array();

function associate($element) 
{
    $assDays[$element] = 0;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_walk($days, 'associate'));
echo "</pre>";
```

Doesn't work. I'm sure the problem is that I don't pass the values to the function **associate** but I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [array_fill_keys](http://php.net/array_fill_keys):

```
$assDays = array_fill_keys($days, 0);
```